# How to use Firebase Extension Translate Text in Firestore inside a field that contain array?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-translate

In Firestore I have a path "company/bbb/travels/passngers".
and each passengers document hold an array. One of the array field is "name" and I want google translate extension translate it automatically.

I don't see anything about this in the documentation....
Is  the Firestore  extension don't know how to handle a field with array?
I don't see nothing about this in the documentation

My structure:

```
passngers:[ 0:{name:"ron",age:32} ,1:{name:"san",age:56}    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/firestore-translate-text#translate-text) of the Translate Text Firebase extension, a configuration parameter is the `Input field name` which is the name of the field that contains the string that you want to translate.

Since your field is an array the Translate Text extension will translate the whole array using the Cloud Translation API and currently is not possible to just translate the array field that you want to choose.

Comment: it is not working... it translate the array to null...it is not pass each array element and translate it as you wrote....

Comment: It might be well possible that arrays are not being translated as we might expect it to do it by a human being, since for example `0:{name:"ron",age:32}` can be unexpected string for the Google Translate API without parsing it first.

Comment: so it is can not translate array.....